# Нужно отобразить цвета светофора через определенный период времени

Tags: python

Смотрел на библиотеку `datatime`, но не знаю как это реализовать.

Из условий:

- все должно происходить в классе TrafficLight
- должен быть 1 метод running
- атрибут класса __сolor в котором будут цвета ("Красный", "Желтый", "Зеленый")
- они должны отображаться в консоли в промежутках времени ("Красный": через 7 секунд, "Желтый" через 2 секунды, "Зеленый" - через 7 секунд)

Попытка, но как отобразить их через время не понятно

```py
class TrafficLight:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color

    def running(self):
        for key, value in self._color.items():
            print(key)


traf = TrafficLight(color={
    "Красный": 7,
    "Желтый": 2,
    "Зеленый": 7})
traf.running()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в подробности смысла задачи, то как пример можно реализовать вот так.

```py
from time import sleep

class TrafficLight:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color
    def running(self):
        for key, value in self._color.items():
            sleep(value)
            print(key)


traf = TrafficLight(color={
    "Красный": 7,
    "Желтый": 2,
    "Зеленый": 7})
traf.running()
```

Оговорка вначале потому, что это работает не совсем логично для реального мира. Но задача решена согласно вашим условиям и с вашим же кодом в основе.